# org-mode table/matrix in latex export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have an issue when exporting a table using *matrix environments. The align string appears in the cell content, whatever it is specified or not

```
#+CAPTION: my matrix
#+ATTR_LATEX: :mode displaymath :environment pmatrix 
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

#+CAPTION: my matrix
#+ATTR_LATEX: :mode displaymath :environment pmatrix :align ccc
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
```

[image: result]

Any idea about how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `displaymath` by `math`. 
So the header of your table should look like this:

```
#+ATTR_latex: :mode math :environment pmatrix :align ccc
```

Comment: According to the doc, `displaymath` is not a possible value for the `:mode` attribute.  However, using `table` (a possible value) does exhibit the same erroneous behavior.  Possibly a bug?